# Scheduled Executor in Scala

Tags: scala, scheduled-tasks

In Java I can use [Scheduled Executor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) to schedule tasks to run after a given delay. I can use it in Scala but I wonder if there is a *Scala* API for that.

Is there any Scala API (as opposed to `Scheduled Executor` in Java) to schedule tasks?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Akka has something similar with schedulers:

http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.1.4/#akka.actor.Scheduler

You can obtain one from the actor system:

```
val actorSystem = ActorSystem()
val scheduler = actorSystem.scheduler
val task = new Runnable { def run() { log.info("Hello") } }
implicit val executor = actorSystem.dispatcher

scheduler.schedule(
  initialDelay = Duration(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS),
  interval = Duration(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS),
  runnable = task)
```

If you are using Akka or something based on it, like Play, that would be the way to go.

Comment: Why do people think Scala == Akka?

Comment: Ohh thank you for writing that.. I am new to Scala and everytime I Google anything about Scala, I am finding answers related to Akka..
Your comment makes it much clear for me.

Comment: @marius This works for me only with the `println` function. Do I need to do something else to make it work for any other functions (specifically, a method of the same class).

Comment: Looks like this wasn't working for me in the controllers layer for an `Action.async` type class method. Don't really know the reason for that but it worked for me in another layer of the project.

Comment: Akka is like a virus.

Answer (score 9):

I have been looking for a scala api for scheduled execution as well.

Java's ScheduledExecutor:

- uses a thread pool for running the scheduler and operating the timeouts, and so does not require a Thread per timeout
- No akka needed

I wrote a little scala wrapper for the single task scheduling. See the gist:
https://gist.github.com/platy/8f0e634c64d9fb54559c

Answer (score 4):

You can use scalaz's Task,

```
import scala.concurrent.duration.{FiniteDuration, SECONDS}
import scalaz.concurrent.Task
Task.schedule(Console.println("time's up"), FiniteDuration(5, SECONDS)).runAsync { _ => }
```

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative, there is Monix scheduler too: 
https://monix.io/docs/3x/execution/scheduler.html

It use a Java's `Scheduled Executor` behind, but it is wrapped and transparent.

You need to implement some `Runnable` to be executed, which is lighter than Akka `Actor`.

For example, you can do (taken from the documentation):

```scala
lazy val scheduler =
  Scheduler.singleThread(name="my-thread")

// First execution in 3 seconds, then every 5 seconds
val c = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(
  3, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
  new Runnable {
    def run(): Unit = {
      println("Fixed delay task")
    }
  })

// If we change our mind and want to cancel
c.cancel()
```