# Delay function execution

Tags: scala, multiplexing

What is the simplest way to delay function execution in Scala, something like JavaScript's `setTimeout`? Ideally without spawning thread per delayed execution, i.e. sequential execution. The closest that I was able to find was Akka's [Scheduler](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.1/scala/scheduler.html), but that's an overkill.

For my testing purposes I'm opening thousands of connections, then they get responses in 10 seconds. In node.js it looks like:

```js
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  setTimeout(function() {res.end('Hello World\n');}, 10000 );
}).listen(8080, '127.0.0.1');
```

But what would be the closest Scala version of doing the same? I don't care if `res.end` is going to be executed in multiple threads or queued in a single one.

Comment: Possible duplicate, I'm not sure this answer helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16629357/1296806  but maybe if you want a junky one-off for testing.

Comment: You can also have a look at this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16359849/scala-scheduledfuture

Answer (score 26):

Tired of getting flak for answering the question for simplest too simply, here are the standard JVM idioms:

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_65).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> import java.util.{Timer,TimerTask}
import java.util.{Timer, TimerTask}

scala> val timer = new Timer
timer: java.util.Timer = java.util.Timer@2d9ffd6f

scala> def delay(f: () => Unit, n: Long) = timer.schedule(new TimerTask() { def run = f() }, n)
delay: (f: () => Unit, n: Long)Unit

scala> delay(() => println("Done"), 1000L)

scala> Done


scala> import java.util.concurrent._
import java.util.concurrent._

scala> val x = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2)
x: java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService = java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor@2c5d529e

scala> x.schedule(new Callable[Int]() { def call = { println("Ran"); 42 }}, 1L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
res3: java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture[Int] = java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@3ab0f534

scala> Ran
```

There is no API for scheduling a delayed task in the standard library, but you can make an `ExecutionContext` with a fixed delay, in order to use Scala `Future`.

```
scala> import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent._

scala> implicit val xx = new ExecutionContext() {
     | def reportFailure(t: Throwable) = t.printStackTrace()
     | def execute(r: Runnable) = x.schedule(new Callable[Unit]() { def call = r.run() }, 1L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
     | }
xx: scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext = $anon$1@40d3ab8b

scala> Future(println("hello"))
res4: scala.concurrent.Future[Unit] = List()

scala> hello

scala> Future(42)
res5: scala.concurrent.Future[Int] = List()                

scala> .value
res6: Option[scala.util.Try[Int]] = Some(Success(42))
```

Or you can use Akka's scheduler, which is the canonical answer at [Scheduled Executor in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16625464/1296806)

The old one-liner:

Simplest is still just `future { blocking(Thread.sleep(10000L)); "done" }`

but I wanted to place an ad for this guy, which I just came across, which gives you a progress indicator or intermediate value.  I kind of wish it had a different name, is all.

```
scala> import concurrent._
import concurrent._

scala> import ExecutionContext.Implicits._
import ExecutionContext.Implicits._

scala> import duration._
import duration._

scala> val deadline = 60.seconds.fromNow
deadline: scala.concurrent.duration.Deadline = Deadline(38794983852399 nanoseconds)

scala> new DelayedLazyVal(() => deadline.timeLeft.max(Duration.Zero), blocking {
     | Thread.sleep(deadline.timeLeft.toMillis)
     | Console println "Working!"
     | })
res9: scala.concurrent.DelayedLazyVal[scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration] = scala.concurrent.DelayedLazyVal@50b56ef3

scala> res9()
res10: scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration = 23137149130 nanoseconds

scala> res9.isDone
res11: Boolean = false

scala> res9()
res12: scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration = 12499910694 nanoseconds

scala> res9()
res13: scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration = 5232807506 nanoseconds

scala> Working!


scala> res9.isDone
res14: Boolean = true

scala> res9()
res15: scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration = 0 days
```

Here's an alternative formulation with Either, to calculate a value after a delay.  Using `Left` of course when there is still time `Left`.

```
scala> new DelayedLazyVal(()=> if (deadline.hasTimeLeft) Left(deadline.timeLeft) else
     | Right("Working!"), blocking(Thread.sleep(deadline.timeLeft.toMillis)))
res21: scala.concurrent.DelayedLazyVal[Product with Serializable with scala.util.Either[scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration,String]] = scala.concurrent.DelayedLazyVal@78f9c6f2

scala> res21()
res22: Product with Serializable with scala.util.Either[scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration,String] = Left(28553649064 nanoseconds)

scala> res21()
res23: Product with Serializable with scala.util.Either[scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration,String] = Left(9378334087 nanoseconds)

scala> res21.isDone
res24: Boolean = false

scala> res21()
res25: Product with Serializable with scala.util.Either[scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration,String] = Right(Working!)

scala> res21.isDone
res26: Boolean = true
```

Comment: won't it result in thousands of threads sleeping for 10 seconds?

Comment: Is there a non-blocking solution?