# Delay execution in scala

Tags: scala

I want to delay the execution of a scala script.
The purpose it to provide some user readability.
Wait for like 1 second or so, between printing new lines.

A naive(blocking) way to do so is

```
for(a<-1 to 100000){
  //do nothing
}
```

Any cleaner ways to so using Scala API

Comment: Use java interop: `Thread.sleep(1000L)`

Comment: If you want non-blocking approach, use [Java Timers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044726/how-to-set-a-timer-in-java) or [Akka Schedulers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16625464/scheduled-executor-in-scala)

Comment: What's your reasoning for `for(a<-1 to 100000){` to equate to one second?

Comment: @noahlz Thanks, that never struck me.. :)

Comment: @KevinMeredith none, just me being a noob

Comment: Btw, Thread.sleep can throw an InterruptedException...usually doesn't happen, but be aware